# How to scanf in a void function and have the results come out in the main function to be used in another void in C?

Tags: c

The voids themselves work fine, but how do I recall a variable from one void to another?
The problem im having is that the name in `enter_user_name(void)` isn't being put into the printf in `enter_user_exam(void)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void enter_user_name(void);
void enter_user_exam(void);

int main()
{

    enter_user_name();
    enter_user_exam();
    return 0;
}

// Define the function:
// Note: No semicolon after function name
void enter_user_name()
{
    /* Need next two lines for printf() operation */
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stdin, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    char guyname[32]= {0};
    char lastname[32]= {0};
    printf("Enter your first and last name : ");
    scanf("%s %s", &guyname, &lastname);

    guyname[0] = toupper( guyname[0] );
    int len = strlen(guyname);
    for(int i=1; i<len ; i++)
    {
        guyname[i] = tolower( guyname[i]);
    }

    lastname[0] = toupper( lastname[0] );
    int len1 = strlen(lastname);
    for(int k=1; k<len1; k++)
    {
        lastname[k]= tolower( lastname[k]);
    }

    printf("Your name is %s %s\n", guyname, lastname);

}

void enter_user_exam(void)
{
    /* Need next two lines for printf() operation */
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stdin, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    int option = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    char guyname[32]= {0};
    char lastname[32]= {0};
    int maxscore = 100;
    int scores[3] = {0};
    float average = ((float)sum/(maxscore*3)) * 100;

    for( int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("Assuming the max score is 100, what was your score for exam %i?\n",i+1);
        scanf("%i",&scores [i]);
        while(scores [i]>maxscore)
        {

            printf("Your score should not be higher than max score.\n");
            printf("What was your score for exam %i?\n",i+1 );
            scanf("%i",&scores [i]);

        }

    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    average = ((float)sum/(maxscore*3)) * 100;
    printf("%s %s, the exam scores you input are %i ,%i ,and %i\n\n",guyname,lastname, scores[0], scores[1], scores[2]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to make `stdout` (or `stdin`) unbuffered. Just `fflush` `stdout` when needed.

Comment: `scanf("%s %s", &guyname, &lastname);` No need to place a `&` as %s expects `char *` mean just the base address f the array is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to get data back from a function:

1. The function returns the data
2. The function gets a pointer to the data as argument, and fills it in
3. Data is stored in global variables

In my opinion, the list above is in priority order. The best solution is often to return the data (though you have to be careful not to return pointers to local variables), and the worst it to have global variables.